# Receiving no data when testing bound text

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have searched high and low for an answer to this question, but I could not find one that works in my instance. I am currently trying to test that some text is bound correctly (I can see it), but I cannot get the actual text when testing. Below is some code.

```
<h3>Borrowing Potential: {{$ctrl.borrowingPotential.value | currency}} as of 
{{$ctrl.borrowingPotential.timeStamp | date:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a':EST}} EST</h3>
```

__

```
fit("should have a borrowing potential calculated", function () {
    var tab = element(by.css('[ng-click="$ctrl.setSelectedTab($ctrl.tabs.summary)"]'));
    tab.click();
    var parent = element(by.tagName("member-summary"));
    var borrowingPotential = parent.element(by.tagName("h3"));
    expect(borrowingPotential.getAttribute("value")).toContain("Some Text");

});
```

Essentially, I click a tab which displays a custom component called "member-summary", then I attempt to access that element via web driver. It is the only instance of member-summary on this page. However, when I access either parent or borrowingPotential, getText() returns an empty string, and getAttribute returns a null type.

Note: I have also attempted to access the binding directly, again with no results. This does not work because the binding is not considered a child of the parent element (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3147).

How can I get that text and then test that it displayed is correct?

---

As requested, below is the html from the Chrome debugger. As you can see, the bindings have been replaced with text.

```
<h3 class="ng-binding">Borrowing Potential: -$48,939,539.14 as of 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM EST</h3>
```

Comment: Can you paste your HTML here like it is shown in on the page (with DevTools in Chrome or something)

Comment: I'll edit the main post for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your provided info you should only retrieve the text of the `h3`-element because it isn't an `input`-field. You can use `getText()` for it. Your code would be like this

```js
fit("should have a borrowing potential calculated", function() {
  var tab = element(by.css('[ng-click="$ctrl.setSelectedTab($ctrl.tabs.summary)"]'));
  tab.click();
  var parent = element(by.tagName("member-summary"));
  var borrowingPotential = parent.element(by.tagName("h3"));
  // Replace the `getValue()` with `getText()`
  expect(borrowingPotential.getText()).toContain("Some Text");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are correct! I tried to vote for you, but I do not yet have enough reputation.